# Flutter: CocoaPods's specs repository is too out-of-date to satisfy dependencies

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, cocoapods, podfile

Current, I was trying to add `firebase_core: ^0.5.0+1` and `firebase_crashlytics: ^0.2.1+1` packages in my flutter project with the latest versions, It works without any trouble in Android but in iOS, it is not working and giving error. So now how to run my project with the latest package in the iOS Flutter project?

I also tried to `pod repo update` but it is still not working

I am getting this error on `flutter run`

```
CocoaPods' output:
↳
      Preparing

    Analyzing dependencies

    Inspecting targets to integrate
      Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)

    Finding Podfile changes
      A firebase_crashlytics
      - Flutter
      - contact_picker
      - device_info
      - file_picker
      - firebase_auth
      - firebase_core
      - firebase_messaging
      - flutter_keyboard_visibility
      - flutter_local_notifications
      - flutter_webview_plugin
      - image_picker
      - path_provider
      - phone_number
      - share
      - shared_preferences
      - sqflite
      - url_launcher

    Fetching external sources
    -> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
    -> Fetching podspec for `contact_picker` from `.symlinks/plugins/contact_picker/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `device_info` from `.symlinks/plugins/device_info/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `file_picker` from `.symlinks/plugins/file_picker/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_auth` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`
    firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '6.26.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_core` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`
    firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '6.26.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_crashlytics` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_crashlytics/ios`
    firebase_crashlytics: Using Firebase SDK version '6.26.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_messaging` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_messaging/ios`
    firebase_messaging: Using Firebase SDK version '6.26.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `flutter_keyboard_visibility` from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_keyboard_visibility/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `flutter_local_notifications` from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_local_notifications/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `flutter_webview_plugin` from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_webview_plugin/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `image_picker` from `.symlinks/plugins/image_picker/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `path_provider` from `.symlinks/plugins/path_provider/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `phone_number` from `.symlinks/plugins/phone_number/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `share` from `.symlinks/plugins/share/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `shared_preferences` from `.symlinks/plugins/shared_preferences/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `sqflite` from `.symlinks/plugins/sqflite/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `url_launcher` from `.symlinks/plugins/url_launcher/ios`

    Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
      CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_1_6_1.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/4.3.2/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/4.3.2/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_0_3_5.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.34.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.26.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.26.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.26.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_2_4_b.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/2/4/b/PhoneNumberKit/3.3.1/PhoneNumberKit.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/2/4/b/PhoneNumberKit/3.2.0/PhoneNumberKit.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.26.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_f_4_e.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/f/4/e/FMDB/2.7.5/FMDB.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.26.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_2_d_6.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/2/d/6/FirebaseMessaging/4.7.1/FirebaseMessaging.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/2/d/6/FirebaseMessaging/4.4.1/FirebaseMessaging.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_6_f_9.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/6/f/9/FirebaseAnalyticsInterop/1.5.0/FirebaseAnalyticsInterop.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_8_b_d.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/8/b/d/FirebaseCore/6.10.4/FirebaseCore.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_3_6_0.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/6/0/FirebaseInstanceID/4.8.0/FirebaseInstanceID.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_0_8_4.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/6.7.2/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/6.7.2/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/6.7.2/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/6.7.2/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/6.7.2/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_e_c_d.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/e/c/d/Protobuf/4.0.0-rc1/Protobuf.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/e/c/d/Protobuf/3.13.0/Protobuf.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_6_3_6.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/6/3/6/FirebaseAuth/6.9.2/FirebaseAuth.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/6/3/6/FirebaseAuth/6.5.3/FirebaseAuth.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_4_2_7.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/4/2/7/FirebaseAuthInterop/1.1.0/FirebaseAuthInterop.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_c_e_3.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/c/e/3/GTMSessionFetcher/1.4.0/GTMSessionFetcher.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/c/e/3/GTMSessionFetcher/1.4.0/GTMSessionFetcher.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_e_7_d.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/e/7/d/FirebaseCrashlytics/4.6.2/FirebaseCrashlytics.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/e/7/d/FirebaseCrashlytics/4.1.1/FirebaseCrashlytics.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_2_f_7.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/2/f/7/FirebaseInstallations/1.7.0/FirebaseInstallations.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_0_b_5.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/b/5/PromisesObjC/1.2.11/PromisesObjC.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_0_6_a.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/6/a/GoogleDataTransport/7.5.1/GoogleDataTransport.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_b_c_f.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/b/c/f/GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport/3.2.0/GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_6_1_e.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/6/1/e/nanopb/2.30906.0/nanopb.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
    [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "GoogleDataTransport":
      In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
        GoogleDataTransport (= 7.4.0, ~> 7.4)

      In Podfile:
        firebase_crashlytics (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_crashlytics/ios`) was resolved to 0.2.1-1, which depends on
          Firebase/Crashlytics (~> 6.26.0) was resolved to 6.26.0, which depends on
            FirebaseCrashlytics (~> 4.1.1) was resolved to 4.1.1, which depends on
              GoogleDataTransport (~> 6.1)


    You have either:
     * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
     * changed the constraints of dependency `GoogleDataTransport` inside your development pod `firebase_crashlytics`.
       You should run `pod update GoogleDataTransport` to apply changes you've made.

    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:328:in `raise_error_unless_state'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:310:in `block in unwind_for_conflict'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:308:in `tap'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:308:in `unwind_for_conflict'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:257:in `process_topmost_state'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:182:in `resolve'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43:in `resolve'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0.rc.1/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:94:in `resolve'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0.rc.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1074:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0.rc.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0.rc.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1072:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0.rc.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in `analyze'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0.rc.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:414:in `analyze'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0.rc.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:239:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0.rc.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0.rc.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:238:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0.rc.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:160:in `install!'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0.rc.1/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0.rc.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0.rc.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'

Error output from CocoaPods:
↳

    [!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `10.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.

Error: CocoaPods's specs repository is too out-of-date to satisfy dependencies.
To update the CocoaPods specs, run:
  pod repo update

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro.
```

Comment: Run `pod repo update`

Comment: try.. -- flutter clean, 
pod repo update, 
deleted /ios/Pods/ and /ios/Podfile.lock

Comment: I tried flutter clean and that worked for me.

Answer (score 311):

This worked for me:

1. `flutter clean`
2. Delete /ios/Pods
3. Delete /ios/Podfile.lock
4. `flutter pub get`
5. from inside ios folder: `pod install`
6. `flutter run`

Comment: Before these steps, go to XCode Target - Runner - Deployment Info and change iOS target version to iOS 10.0

Comment: What if I have a package that only runs above iOS 12?

Comment: The above plus ```flutter upgrade``` worked for me

Comment: It seems the above including these comments must be repeated every so often.  This is the second time I have followed directions like these.  Thank you : )

Answer (score 80):

How I resolved this...

#### Remove pod completely

> 1. Go to /ios folder inside your Project.
> 2. Delete Podfile.lock (YourPoject/ios/Podfile.lock)
> 3. run cmd `pod repo remove trunk`

Now you have removed the pod completely.

#### Update pod repo

Now run one of the following according to the chip of your Mac (thanks to @Kamal Panara for identifying this):

###### For Intel chip users

Run this in the `ios` directory of your Flutter app:

```bash
pod install --repo-update
```

###### For M1 chip Users

Install ffi first (if not already installed) in regular terminal using command:

```bash
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
```

then run:

```bash
arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update
```

Note if you are getting an error of

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "cloud_firestore":
  In Podfile:
    cloud_firestore (from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`)

Specs satisfying the `cloud_firestore (from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

[!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `9.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.
```

then go to the podfile at line
just uncomment the line and make it similar like below.

```
platform :ios, '12.0'
```

Now re-run this cmd.

```bash
arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update
```

Now this time it will work fine.

### flutter clean

now run

```bash
flutter clean
```

then

```bash
flutter run
```

Enjoy.

Comment: worked liked a charm.. thanks. My MacBook is m1 pro

Comment: Just "arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update" fixed my all problems thanks!

Comment: The perfect solution for M1 chips. Many thanks

Comment: This worked on M1 Mac - 2023 April

Comment: If you're getting errors like permission denied, use `arch -x86_64 /bin/bash -l` and then run `gem install ffi` and `pod install --repo-update --allow-root`

Answer (score 35):

This worked for me, NO need to run flutter clean

1. goto ios folder inside your project
2. remove Podfile.lock
3. run `flutter pub get` if your `Podfile` is out of date or non-existent.
4. run `pod install` under ios folder

Comment: I think with flutter 1.20 and windows we dont have the "pod" executable/cli inside IOs folder, tried "flutter pod install", "pod install", nothing works. I tried just flutter pub get it didnt work too

Comment: @darthRodolfo cocopods is ios/mac specific.

Comment: + If your build gets stuck, run flutter clean && flutter run

Comment: The second point worked for me! Thanks man

Answer (score 16):

For me, simply removing `podfile.lock` and re-running with `flutter run` did the trick.

Answer (score 8):

I was having a similar issue with the same error message when trying to add new features to my Flutter app. I was using Flutter 3.0.5 and didn't want to update it, but I kept encountering this error.

After a week of trying to fix the issue with little tweaks here and there, I finally found a solution that worked for me. I ran the following command in my Flutter project :

```
flutter upgrade && flutter clean && rm -rf ios/Pods && rm ios/Podfile.lock && flutter packages get && flutter pub get && cd ios && pod install && cd .. && flutter run
```

This command upgrades Flutter, cleans the project, removes the Pods directory and Podfile.lock file, and reinstalls the packages and dependencies. It also runs the "pod install" command in the ios directory to install the iOS dependencies and then runs the flutter run command to start the app.

This worked for me and I was able to add new features without encountering the same error again. I hope it helps others who are running into this issue.

Answer (score 3):

If your Run folder dont have  /ios/Podfile.lock
you just need open your IOS foler in terminal
and run :
$ pod repo update

Answer (score 3):

Try the following steps. It worked for me:

- flutter clean
- delete /ios/Pods
- delete /ios/Podfile.lock

In the ios folder, run the following command:

```
pod install --repo-update
```

Finally, perform the following:

```
flutter run
```

Comment: +1 This worked for me! The important thing is, after deleting the Pods folder and Podfile.lock file, `pod install --repo-update` requires `flutter pub get` first.

Comment: Great, this worked for me!

Answer (score 3):

in my case it was fixed by :

first of all: deleting podfile.lock

then running:
`flutter clean`

after that:

```
flutter pub get
```

finally : go to iOS folder
cd ios
`pod install`

### and the project will run now

if you are opening project for the first time then:
first of all: delete podfile.lock

1=> delete pub spec.lock because it sometimes project cached old flutter versions

2=> flutter clean

3=> flutter pub get

4=> go to iOS folder cd ios `pod install`

5=> if you got any error related to this:

```
Error: Field 'wLanguage' cannot be nullable or have type 'Null', it must be `int`, `double`, `Pointer`, or a subtype of `Struct` or `Union`
```

so pls run : `flutter pub upgrade` to update packages also

and finally it will work

Answer (score 1):

This issue happens when there is a mismatch in the pod files.

The solution is pointed out by Flutter itself in the debug console.
[image]

The common mistake that people make is run the command directly in the project. You have to run it in the ios folder of the project.

1. Set the path of your terminal to the ios folder. Just add `/ios` after your project path. Eg - `cd /Users/workfolder/flutter_project/ios`
2. Run the command `pod repo update` or just `pod update`.

It will download all the dependencies and fix all the issue with the pod. Then you can run your app normally.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me,

1. Delete the Podfile.lock file
2. Run -> flutter pub get in terminal
3. Run -> arch -x86_64 pod install in terminal
   After that, you are ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

Delete these 2 files

```
1. ios/pods
2. ios/podfile.lock
3. flutter pub get
```

then navigate to the ios folder

```
4. cd ios
5. pod install
```

wait for the pods to install and run your project

Answer (score -3):

Try the following steps :

```
pod ios

pod cache clean --all

Pod clean

pod deintegrate

sudo gem install cocoapods-deintegrate cocoapods-clean

sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi

arch -x86_64 pod repo update

arch -x86_64 pod install
```

Comment: leave proper comments what all this command do and why

Answer (score -4):

In my case:

1. Open android studio for mac.
2. Go to ios folder.
3. Delete podfile and podfile.lock
4. Run flutter pub get.
5. Go to ios folder by terminal and run "pod install".

[image]

Comment: Don't delete Podfile

Comment: Dont delete Podfile, you will lost configs