# I'm getting error during flutter run. Error has something to pod file. Does anyone know how to resolve?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, cocoapods

I did pod repo update. It's not working. I am running on Mac. I tried reinstalling cocapods but It didn't help either. How to do I resolve this? Really been stuck on this for a day now. This is the error its giving :

Error: CocoaPods's specs repository is too out-of-date to satisfy dependencies.
To update the CocoaPods specs, run:
pod repo update

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 13.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 13 in debug mode...
Running pod install...
CocoaPods' output:
↳
  Preparing

Analyzing dependencies

Inspecting targets to integrate
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)

Finding Podfile changes
  - Flutter
  - cloud_firestore
  - firebase_auth
  - firebase_core
  - firebase_dynamic_links
  - firebase_storage
  - geolocator_apple
  - google_sign_in
  - image_cropper
  - image_picker
  - path_provider_ios
  - qr_code_scanner
  - share_plus
  - sqflite
  - url_launcher_ios

Fetching external sources
-> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
-> Fetching podspec for `cloud_firestore` from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`
cloud_firestore: Using Firebase SDK version '8.9.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_auth` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`
firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '8.9.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_core` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '8.9.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_dynamic_links` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_dynamic_links/ios`
firebase_dynamic_links: Using Firebase SDK version '8.9.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_storage` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_storage/ios`
firebase_storage: Using Firebase SDK version '8.9.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
-> Fetching podspec for `geolocator_apple` from `.symlinks/plugins/geolocator_apple/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `google_sign_in` from `.symlinks/plugins/google_sign_in/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `image_cropper` from `.symlinks/plugins/image_cropper/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `image_picker` from `.symlinks/plugins/image_picker/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `path_provider_ios` from `.symlinks/plugins/path_provider_ios/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `qr_code_scanner` from `.symlinks/plugins/qr_code_scanner/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `share_plus` from `.symlinks/plugins/share_plus/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `sqflite` from `.symlinks/plugins/sqflite/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `url_launcher_ios` from `.symlinks/plugins/url_launcher_ios/ios`

Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
  CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_0_3_5.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/8.10.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_d_4_0.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/d/4/0/GoogleSignIn/6.1.0/GoogleSignIn.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_3_7_4.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/7/4/TOCropViewController/2.6.0/TOCropViewController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_0_2_a.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/2/a/MTBBarcodeScanner/5.0.11/MTBBarcodeScanner.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_f_4_e.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/f/4/e/FMDB/2.7.5/FMDB.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/8.9.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/CoreOnly":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    Firebase/CoreOnly (= 8.7.0)

  In Podfile:
    firebase_core (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`) was resolved to 1.10.6, which depends on
      Firebase/CoreOnly (= 8.9.0)


You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * changed the constraints of dependency `Firebase/CoreOnly` inside your development pod `firebase_core`.
   You should run `pod update Firebase/CoreOnly` to apply changes you've made.

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:317:in `raise_error_unless_state'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:299:in `block in unwind_for_conflict'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:297:in `tap'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:297:in `unwind_for_conflict'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:257:in `process_topmost_state'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:182:in `resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43:in `resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:94:in `resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1078:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1076:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:416:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:241:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:240:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:161:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'

Error: CocoaPods's specs repository is too out-of-date to satisfy dependencies.
To update the CocoaPods specs, run:
pod repo update

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 13.
```

Comment: run `pod repo update`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64443888/flutter-cocoapodss-specs-repository-is-too-out-of-date-to-satisfy-dependencies

Comment: I'm following this answer right now. I think it will be resolved

Answer (score 1):

Well, basically your CocoaPods setup is going to break. You are going to have to manually delete any local copies of the Specs repository and re-clone the new version of the Specs repository. You can do that with the following below commands:

After a lot of solution applying, I found a way that has been successful in solving this error, it goes something like this

It can be solved by executing the following commands in the terminal.

Go to /ios folder inside your Project.
Delete Podfile.lock (YourPoject/ios/Podfile.lock)
For Intel chipusers

Run pod install --repo-update (Make sure your cd into the iOS directory of the flutter app)
For M1 chip Users

install ffi first (if not) In regular terminal using command: sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi then arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update

Run flutter clean

Once complete, rebuild your Flutter application: flutter run