# cannot run the flutter app after firebase connection

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, installation, cocoapods

After i added the `GoogleService-Info.plist` file to Runner on xcode, I get this error. 
(I work on an M1 Chip MacBook Air)
[image: This is the error i get when i try to run the app]

I uninstalled each cocoapods version, and installed again using the ARM version (`sudo arch -x86_64 gem install cocoapods`).
But nothing changed.

**Edit:** Just tried the `pod install` method inside the ios folder and this is what happened;

```
Analyzing dependencies
cloud_firestore: Using Firebase SDK version '8.11.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '8.11.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '8.11.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "cloud_firestore":
  In Podfile:
    cloud_firestore (from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`)

Specs satisfying the `cloud_firestore (from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

[!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `9.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.
```

Comment: How did you add google-service file ? copy and paste or import ?

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors; see [ask].

Comment: I added the google-service file using Add Files to "Runner"... method on xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Final edit:** I solved it thanks to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64443888/flutter-cocoapodss-specs-repository-is-too-out-of-date-to-satisfy-dependencies). The problem was that there's no `Podfile.lock` in the `/ios` folder.

Answer (score 0):

you need first to upgrade your package by write "**pub upgrade**" command
after it try to update podfile as below setups :

1. inside terminal move to ios folder "**cd ios**"
2. enter "**pod update**" command
3. if above point not working try "**pod install**" command

Comment: unfortunately didn't work. nothing has changed on my podfile actually.