# Error :: CocoaPods installed but not working.You appear to have CocoaPods installed but it is not working

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods

```
CocoaPods installed but not working.
        You appear to have CocoaPods installed but it is not working.
        This can happen if the version of Ruby that CocoaPods was installed with is different from the one being used to invoke it.
        This can usually be fixed by re-installing CocoaPods.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnpBh.png)

[sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.11.0
Password:
Successfully installed cocoapods-1.11.0
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-1.11.0
Done installing documentation for cocoapods after 2 seconds
1 gem installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyYaq.png)

Comment: Hi, any update on whether you fount a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

You should try this

1. flutter clean
2. delete /ios/Pods
3. delete /ios/Podfile.lock
4. flutter pub get
5. from inside ios folder: pod install
6. flutter run

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66001187/19247433

Comment: still same error ,,CocoaPods installed but not working

Answer (score 0):

check `pod --version`, if return something like this

> 1: from /Users/macbookpro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/array/conversions.rb:8:in `<top (required)>' /Users/macbookpro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/array/conversions.rb:108:in` class:Array': undefined method `deprecator' for ActiveSupport:Module (NoMethodError)
> Did you mean?  deprecate_constant

there is incompatible active_support version. Try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77238468/12468283)